# Send e-mail according to selected value

Tags: php, actionscript-3, email, flash-cs6

I've got a banner where the user can fill out their information (name, e-mail, phone number) and they can select a shop from the "ComboBox" list. Upon submitting the form the information goes to one specific e-mail address. What I'd like to do is to send the information according to the value that has been selected from the shop list.

For example if the user chooses **shop A** the e-mail goes to **recipient A**, and if **shop B** is selected the information would be sent to **recipient B**.

How would I achieve this?

```
/*ActionScript 3.0 */

// custom function we create to populate the comboBox list
function addShopsToList ():void {
shopList.addItem( { label: "Shop A" } );    
shopList.addItem( { label: "Shop B" } );    
}
// Run function above now
addShopsToList ();

// build variable name for the URL Variables loader
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables;

// Build the varSend variable
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("form_parse_rus.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

// handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
// remove processing clip
name_txt.text = "";
email_txt.text = "";
phone_txt.text = "";

// Load the response from php here
status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;
  }

 // Add event listener for submit button click
 submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndSend);

 // function ValidateAndSend
 function ValidateAndSend (event:MouseEvent):void {

// validate fields
if(!name_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
} else if (!email_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Pleaser enter your e-mail";
} else if (!phone_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Please enter your phone number";
} else {

    // All is good, send the data now to PHP

    // ready the variables in our form for sending
    variables.userName = name_txt.text;
    variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;       
    variables.userPhone = phone_txt.text;
    variables.userShop = shopList.value;

    // Send the data to PHP now
    varLoader.load(varSend);

} // close else condition for error handling

 } // close validate and send function
```

**The PHP script responsible for sending the e-mails:**

**EDIT:**

```
<?php

// Create local variables from the Flash ActionScript posted variables
$senderName   = $_POST['userName'];
$senderEmail     = $_POST['userEmail'];
$senderPhone = $_POST['userPhone'];

if(isset($_POST['userShop'])  == "Shop A" ){
$senderShop   = "recipient_A_@mail.com";
}
elseif($_POST['userShop'] == "Shop B"){
     $senderShop   = "recipient_B_@mail.com";
}


// Strip slashes on the Local typed-in variables for security and run any php based error check here
$senderName   = stripslashes($senderName);
$senderEmail     = stripslashes($senderEmail);
$senderMessage   = stripslashes($senderMessage); 

$to = "$senderShop";             
$from = "$senderEmail";
$subject = "Mushroom vs Master";
$message = "Mushroom vs Master:

Nimi: $senderName 
Email: $senderEmail
Telefon: $senderPhone
Esindus: $userShop";


// $headers Variables
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text\r\n"; 
$to = "$to";
    // Send the email
    mail( $senderShop, $subject, $message, $headers);


    // The flash ActionScript is looking for a return variable of "return_msg"
    $my_msg = "Thank you $senderName, for submitting.";
    // Print the data back to flash who is patiently waiting for it in the onCompleteHandler
    print "return_msg=$my_msg"; 
// Exit script  
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['userShop'])  == "shop A" ){
    $senderShop   = "recipientA@abc.com";
    }
    elseif($_POST['userShop'] == "shop B"){
         $senderShop   = "recipientB@abc.com";
    }
     .....and so on
```

Your mail function will be:

```
mail($senderShop, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I think $senderShop is the just the shop name isn't it? I think you'd want to set the $to value in the code to change where the mail was sent.

Comment: $senderShop is the shop name, yes. Right now the information is still being sent to just one e-mail address.

Comment: Look at my conditional statements.

Comment: I've updated the php script with the code you provided but this still sends the e-mail to one address. What am I missing here?

Comment: please remove `$to` as it doesnt make any sense in addition to this,do `var_dump($_POST['userShop'])` and see what does it prints

Comment: It prints: `string(10)`

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['userShop']) && $_POST['userShop'] == "Shop A"){
    $senderShop   = "recipient_A_@mail.com";
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['userShop']) && $_POST['userShop'] == "Shop B"){
         $senderShop   = "recipient_B_@mail.com";
    }`  Solved it for me.